# Pass aspect ratio as variable into imager

Tags: templating, variable, plugin-imager

I use imager to transform images and I want to pass the image ratio as a variable:

```
{% set customRatio = 1/1 %}

{% set image = craft.assets().one() %}
{% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image,
    { width: 1000, ratio: customRatio })
 %}
 <img src="{{ transformedImage.url }}">
```

This does not work. There is something wrong with how it is passed along. If I pass it as a string: `{% set customRatio = '1/1' %}`. It doesn't work either. (No errors in both cases).

But when I write it directely into the imager markup like this:

```
{% set image = craft.assets().one() %}
{% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image,
    { width: 1000, ratio: 1/1 })
 %}
 <img src="{{ transformedImage.url }}">
```

Then it works. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable assignment is wrong. `{% set customRatio == 1/1 %}` should be `{% set customRatio = 1/1 %}`.

Comment: yeah, okay. I'm an idiot 